# Use std::function for creating callbacks(with support of lambda with capture) or not?

Tags: c++, function, callback, glfw, std-function

I'm writing now input handling with use of glfw for window creation, and stuck with call back function. Trying to wrap it in my own Window class, but for handling labmda with capture need to use std::function, (which i don't sure to be good way?).

```
//example of solution
class MyWindow
{
public:

void SetInputCallback(MyInputCallback callback);
private:
    static void inputCallback(GLFWwindow* Window, int32 key, int32 scancode, int32 action, int32 mods);
        GLFWwindow* window;
MyInputCallback CallbackFunc = nullptr;
}

// cpp
void MyWindow::inputCallback(GLFWwindow* Window, int32 key, int32 scancode, int32 action, int32 mods){
if(CallbackFunc)
CallbackFunc(Window,key,scancode,action,mods);
}

void MyWindow::SetInputCallback(MyInputCallback callback)
{
InputCallbackFunction = callback;
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, inputCallback);
};
```

Want to know if std::function is good(or good enough for doing this?) or it's better to use template/simple typedef with some twicking of code(but it will not support lamda with capture, and also will not be explicit about what my window want to get as callback)

Comment: Both are ok, the question is what is more important for you.


The main drawback of std::function is the runtime cost (it does type erasure, so dynamic memory and so on). If that's ok for you, std::function will probably get you more readable code.
If it's not, template stuff will be more efficient, at the cost of readability (also this is getting somewhat better with the more recent standards.

And by the way, you can be just as strict about what are passed as template using c++20's contracts.

Comment: Thanks for answer, c++ 20 has many good stuff but for now I will support c++ 11+, so maybe std::function will be solution(at least for now)